# Merging two pandas dataframes with common values that are presented in one dataframe as columns and on the other are in rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook, match

I have one dataframe that contains hundreds of columns as clients ID and one row with the total nr of tickets per client ID, it looks like this:
(df1 is a result of several transformation of the original csv file)

```
df1
+-----+----+-----+
| 30  | 5  | 100 |
+-----+----+-----+
| 122 | 40 |  13 |
+-----+----+-----+
```

And another dataframe that has 2 columns, one account_id and client_id, looks like this:

```
df2
+------------+-----------+
| account_id | client_id |
+------------+-----------+
| 4char      | 4         |
+------------+-----------+
| 3char      | 5         |
+------------+-----------+
| 2char      | 30        |
+------------+-----------+
| 16char     | 9         |
+------------+-----------+
| 17char     | 100       |
+------------+-----------+
```

I want to have a single file that contains 3 columns account_id, client_id and total_tickets, that will look like this:

```
df
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| account_id | client_id | total_tickets |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 4char      | 4         | null
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 3char      | 5         | 40
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 2char      | 30        | 122
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 16char     | 9         | null
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 17char     | 100       | 13
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Until now I have reached at this point:
I have created a function that iterrows() on both dataframes, check with isin() function if the client_id of df2 is found in the columns of df1, next I add a new column total_tickets with assign() function on df2

```
f1 = df1, f2 = df2
def populating_df(f1, f2):
    for org_nr in f2.iterrows():
        for col in f1.iterrows():
           matched_org_nr =  f2.client_id.isin(f1.columns)
           if matched_org_nr.any() == True:
               sum_of_tickets_per_col = matched_org_nr
           # create a new column in f2 file with the values of total_tickets for each org number matched
           f2 = f2.loc[:].assign(Total_Tickets=sum_of_tickets_per_col) 
        return f2
```

and I get as a result this table:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| account_id | client_id | total_tickets |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
|  4char     | 4         |False
+------------+-----------+---------------+
|  3char     | 5         | True
+------------+-----------+---------------+
|  2char     | 30        | True
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 16char     | 9         | False
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 17char     | 100       | True
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I would be happy if anyone has any suggestion on how to solve this problem

Comment: for df1 are the `client_id` the headers?

Comment: yes @Datanovice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to melt df1 so you have an observation for each row

you can then merge using outer to the get the keys from both columns

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df1,var_name='client_id',value_name='total_tickets')

df3 = pd.merge(df_melt ,df2,on=['client_id'],how='outer')

#make sure dtypes are the same.

#df_melt ['client_id'] = df_melt ['client_id'].astype(int) 

df3 = df3[["account_id", "client_id", "total_tickets"]].sort_values(
    "account_id", ascending=False
)

print(df3)

     account_id  client_id  total_tickets
3   4char                4            NaN
1   3char                5           40.0
0   2char               30          122.0
2   17char             100           13.0
4   16char               9            NaN
```

Comment: the merge doesn't happen, gives me a value error
```ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat```

Comment: @Denisa do you see this line `#df_melt ['client_id'] = df_melt ['client_id'].astype(int)` run this then run the merge I wasn't sure if your columns were strings or integers originally.

Comment: I get the results of df_melt and looks good, but the merge gives a key error again

Comment: can you `print(df2.dtypes)` and `print(df_melt.dtypes)` and post the results to your main question please?

Comment: was using the wrong df, it prints correct results, checking the last step of printing df3

Comment: ```df3 = pd.merge(df_melt ,df2,on=['client_id'],how='outer')``` this prints 2 columns client_id and total_tickets
So, when I execute the next step 
```df3 = df3[["account_id", "client_id", "total_tickets"]].sort_values( "account_id", ascending=False)``` gives key error account_id not in index @Datanovice

Comment: when I read the csv file I have signed the index_col with account_id, I removed it and the code works perfect now. 
I get the desired results, thank you very much for your help and the fast reaction :)

Comment: unfortunately I can not vote your solution yet so here +1 @Datanovice

Comment: @Denisa you can always upvote the answer and green tick if it answered your issues. happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`merge` is the key, but you have to first transpose the initial data frame, and do some cosmetic changes such as reset its index and provide relevant column names:

The transformation could be:

```
df1.rename({0: 'total_tickets'}).T.rename_axis('client_id').reset_index()
```

giving:

```
   client_index  total_tickets
0            30            122
1             5             40
2           100             13
```

Once this is done, the merge is trivial:

```
result = df2.merge(df1.rename({0: 'total_tickets'}).T.rename_axis('client_id').reset_index(),
                   on='client_id', how='left')
```

giving as expected:

```
  account_id  client_id  total_tickets
0      4char          4            NaN
1      3char          5           40.0
2      2char         30          122.0
3     16char          9            NaN
4     17char        100           13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge`.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="client_id", how='outer')
```

Comment: this won't work you need to do some processing before the merge